# Lotus Dominoes SameTime problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, lotus-notes, sophos

A colleague is having problems with the Lotus SameTime server. It crashes periodically and each time the actual server ST resides on has to be restarted. When you attempt to restart the main service you get a "Lotus Notes Error 0x143" and it doesn't start (have manually killed all ST processes and services before trying this).

Looking through the logs generated, the initial problem seems to be with the StConfiguration and config file in \SameTimeCommunity\Cluster\Services.

Sophos Anti-Virus is also on this box (Win Server 2k3, SP2) and the ST crashes typically coincide with a scan (but not always).

This is a legacy product, so support from IBM is nill. Anyone here have any experience with this that can help point us in a useful direction?

Thanks in advance,

Dustin

Comment: If anybody has any clues, I'd really appreciate it. This is still an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely culprit is one I just dealt with today:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/c21908baf7e06eb085256a39006eae9f/a8c8591582640b2085256d830051d11f?OpenDocument

Keep me posted on your friend's progress!

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton. I was afraid this was going into limbo. I'll let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for a list of 0x143 errors that have been discussed, you can check out the IBM Lotus Domino support forums here:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/Search?SearchView&Query=0x143&SearchOrder=0&Start=1&Count=100

Best of luck!

Cheers!

Angel